# Pandas to_csv only write the data from certain page

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape data from tripadvisor, but from several pages that I tried to scrape, when I try to export it to csv it only shows 1 line of data and gives an error message like this

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

this is my code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g469404-d3780963-Reviews-oa'

for offset in range(0, 30, 10):
    
    url = URL + str(offset) + '-Double_Six_Beach-Seminyak_Kuta_District_Bali.html'
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")    
    
    container = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'_2rspOqPP'})
    
    for r in container:
        reviews = r.find_all('div', {'class': None})

        #the container that contains the elements that I want to scrape has no attributes and use DOM element. So I tried to access div with _2rspOqPP class first then access the div with no attributes from there

        records = []
        for review in reviews:
            user = review.find('a', {'class':'_7c6GgQ6n _37QDe3gr WullykOU _3WoyIIcL'}).text
            country = review.find('div', {'class' : 'DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 NGv7A1lw _2yS548m8 _2cnjB3re _1TAWSgm1 _1Z1zA2gh _2-K8UW3T _1dimhEoy'}).span.text
            date = review.find('div', {'class' : '_3JxPDYSx'}).text
            content = review.find('div', {'class' : 'DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _2nPM5Opx'}).text

            records.append((user, country, date, content))
            df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Name', 'Country', 'Date', 'Content'])
            df.to_csv('doublesix_.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Code updated

```
for r in container:
    reviews = r.find_all('div', {'class': None})
    records = []
    for review in reviews:
        try:
            user = review.find('a', {'class':'_7c6GgQ6n _37QDe3gr WullykOU _3WoyIIcL'}).text
            country = review.find('div', {'class' : 'DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 NGv7A1lw _2yS548m8 _2cnjB3re _1TAWSgm1 _1Z1zA2gh _2-K8UW3T _1dimhEoy'}).span.text
            date = review.find('div', {'class' : '_3JxPDYSx'}).text
            content = review.find('div', {'class' : 'DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _2nPM5Opx'}).text
            
            records.append((user, country, date, content))
        except:
            pass
        

print(records)
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Name', 'Country', 'Date', 'Content'])
df.to_csv('doublesix_.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: you need to append the data and at the end write to csv. think of moving below lines out of loop `df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Name', 'Country', 'Date', 'Content'])
            df.to_csv('doublesix_.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')` and `records = []` before the for loop.

Comment: That is part of the issue. I think there is another issue in that `review.find()` returns `None` thus you can't `None.text`. You will need some exception for handling with a try/except. It essentially died after the first scraped page.

Comment: @astrochun I tried to add the exception handling (I updated my code), it scrapes all the pages but only write the data from the last page and got some exception between the scraped pages

Comment: @astrochun oh I also want to ask something, in the HTML page there is only one div with _2rspOqPP class, but I used find_all() to select the element, does it affect my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `records` out of the `for loops` and unindent the last few lines.

See this:

```python
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g469404-d3780963-Reviews-oa'

country_class = "DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 NGv7A1lw _2yS548m8 _2cnjB3re _1TAWSgm1 _1Z1zA2gh _2-K8UW3T _1dimhEoy"
records = []

for offset in range(0, 30, 10):
    url = main_url + str(offset) + '-Double_Six_Beach-Seminyak_Kuta_District_Bali.html'
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
    }

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")
    container = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_2rspOqPP'})
    for r in container:
        reviews = r.find_all('div', {'class': None})
        for review in reviews:
            try:
                user = review.find('a', {'class': '_7c6GgQ6n _37QDe3gr WullykOU _3WoyIIcL'}).text
                country = review.find('div', {'class': country_class}).span.text
                date = review.find('div', {'class': '_3JxPDYSx'}).text
                content = review.find('div', {'class': 'DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _2nPM5Opx'}).text
                records.append((user, country, date, content))
            except AttributeError:
                pass

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Name', 'Country', 'Date', 'Content'])
df.to_csv('doublesix_.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Output from the `.csv` file:

[image]

Comment: also I have a question, It was working fine when I tried to scrape just 3-10 pages, but when I increase the page until 100 pages I get some error like this

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')"))

do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Yes, slow down with scraping. The server drops the connection because you're sending too many requests.